# Removing duplicates from a list

Tags: tex-core, programming

Is there a LaTeX kernel command to remove duplicates from a list?

The list has the structure

```
\def\alist{john,mary,george,australia,australia}
```

Comment: Can we assume that the list is sorted such that duplicates would appear next to each other? That would simplify the task considerably.

Comment: @Christian: I'm not sure it would: I'm intrigued to see how you'd implement a duplicate-removal approach. (The usual is simply to loop over the 'old' list and build a 'new' one with only the unique elements.)

Comment: @Christian Lindig ...aha! Yes we can assume the list is sorted.

Comment: @Joseph Removing duplicates from an unsorted list takes quadratic effort but only linear effort for a sorted list. I still might not be sufficiently versed in TeX to express this idea.

Comment: @Christian: But you have to sort it first :-)

Comment: @Joseph @Christian with TeX, either sorted or unsorted should be O(n). I was thinking create a command with first element read next, if it exists skip otherwise insert on new list until the end of the list. What I was hoping with Christian's idea was that he was going to offer a solution with TeX's scanner and delimited arguments. \keyword....\keyword->remove \keyword and have some form of recursion.

Comment: @Yiannis: The approach you suggest (read element and insert into new list) is how things are currently done by `\clist_remove_duplicates:Nn`, so that would be my choice too!

Comment: @Joseph And that is basically egreg's solution as well.

Comment: @Yiannis: True, but I would avoid the `\xdef` myself.

Comment: @Joseph why is that?

Comment: @Joseph: this is not the current approach in l3clist. I am coding right now an expl3 solution which we may want to include. The main issue is that to build control sequences from the clist's elements, we need to detokenize them, and this considers two elements as identical if they have the same string representation. I have a way around this, but it will put all the elements with the same detokenization next to each other in the result. Is that ok?

Comment: @Yiannis: Partly 'style' and partly save-stack implications. I favour only doing things globally if they _have_ to be global, and it's quite possible to do the removal here without using global variables. On the save-stack side, it is best not to mix local and global assignments to macros or registers, as it is possible to use up TeX's save stack that way. For the same reason, you'll see that _The TeXbook_ specifies that some 'scratch' registers are local and some are global.

Comment: @Yiannis: using `\xdef` fully expands the elements that you are working with.

Comment: @Bruno: One for another place, I think (but the current implementation does as I said do a mapping over the 'input' list and create an 'output' list)

Comment: @Joseph: now it's without `\xdef` (it wasn't that hard, after all).

Comment: @Joseph: sorry, I was confused by Yiannis' comment on "that's the same as egreg's solution": egreg is building control sequences to check for uniqueness.

Comment: @Bruno: I was referring to the general idea of creating a new list containing entries from the existing one in a loop.

Comment: @Joseph: finished, although I haven't really checked the claim that it is linear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few years later…

First of all, it's better not to use a macro to store lists, but to make a sort of namespace.

Doing it, as well as removing duplicates, is easy with `expl3`. Other functions for managing and using lists can be added by exploiting standard `expl3` features.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\listdefine}{mm}
 {% #1 = list name, #2 = items
  \clist_gclear_new:c { g_yannisl_list_#1_clist }
  \clist_gset:cn { g_yannisl_list_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\listremoveduplicates}{mo}
 {% #1 = list name, #2 = optional new list name
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {% change the list
    \clist_gremove_duplicates:c { g_yannisl_list_#1_clist }
   }
   {% put in a new one
    \clist_clear_new:c { g_yannisl_list_#2_clist }
    \clist_gset_eq:cc { g_yannisl_list_#2_clist } { g_yannisl_list_#1_clist }
    \clist_gremove_duplicates:c { g_yannisl_list_#2_clist }
   }
 }

% Just for the example
\NewDocumentCommand{\listshow}{m}
 {% #1 = list name
  \clist_show:c { g_yannisl_list_#1_clist }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\listdefine{alist}{john,mary,george,australia,australia,john}
\listshow{alist}
\listremoveduplicates{alist}[blist]
\listshow{alist}
\listshow{blist}

\stop
```

Console output:

```
The comma list \g_yannisl_list_alist_clist contains the items (without outer
braces):
>  {john}
>  {mary}
>  {george}
>  {australia}
>  {australia}
>  {john}.
<recently read> }

l.32 \listshow{alist}

?
The comma list \g_yannisl_list_alist_clist contains the items (without outer
braces):
>  {john}
>  {mary}
>  {george}
>  {australia}
>  {australia}
>  {john}.
<recently read> }

l.34 \listshow{alist}

?
The comma list \g_yannisl_list_blist_clist contains the items (without outer
braces):
>  {john}
>  {mary}
>  {george}
>  {australia}.
<recently read> }

l.35 \listshow{blist}
```

If `\listremoveduplicates` is called without the optional argument, then it is itself redefined without duplicates.

### Original answer

```
\makeatletter
\def\removeduplicates#1#2{\begingroup
  \let\@tempa#1%
  \def\@tempb{}%
  \@for\next:=\@tempa\do
    {\@ifundefined{lstel@\next}
      {\edef\@tempb{\@tempb,\next}
       \expandafter\let\csname lstel@\next\endcsname\@empty}
      {}%
    }%
  \edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand#2{\@tempb}}\x
  \expandafter\strip@comma#2\@nil#2}
\def\strip@comma,#1\@nil#2{\def#2{#1}}
\makeatother
\def\alist{john,mary,george,australia,australia,john}

\removeduplicates\alist\blist

\show\blist
\show\alist

\removeduplicates\alist\alist
\show\alist
```

When we look at each list element, say `john`, we see whether `\lstel@john` is undefined; in this case we add the list element to the new list and define the corresponding command. At the end we strip the initial comma. It doesn't work with an empty list, but adding that test is easy.

`\removeduplicates` can receive identical arguments, in this case the new list will overwrite the original one, of course.

Note: edited to avoid the use of `\xdef`

Comment: Thanks, works fine. As is customary I will wait a bit and then accept the answer.

Comment: It's just a loop on all list elements; I'm no expert to tell if it's quadratic or worse. :) Of course, all list elements are assumed to be unexpandable, but one can think variations to cope with this case.

Comment: I am not too sure either, but I just passed a list with about 5000 elements and it removed the duplicates before I could light a cigarette:)

Comment: adding elements one by one makes it quadratic, because each assignmnet will be linear in the size `n` of the clist, and you will end up doing it `n` times. Doing it linearly is more tricky, but feasible.

Comment: @egreg I have a very similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/712084/filter-datatool-db-for-duplicate-values-with-nested-dtlforeach) in context of using datatool. Can we do it there in a similar way?

Comment: @PascalS Sorry, but your problem seems very specific to `datatool`.

Comment: @egreg Never the less, thanks for having a look :)

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to remove duplicates in an almost linear time, without restriction on what the elements can be (except of course that they cannot contain commas without hiding them behind braces).

The hard thing is that adding elements one at a time would automatically lead to a quadratic time, since adding an element to a comma-list (or any token list in fact) takes a time proportional to the length of the list. So we somehow need to put all the elements at once.

Also, the only way that I can think of checking whether an item is a duplicate in an almost constant time is to define one control sequence per item. I am taking this idea from egreg's answer. The problem with that is that it regards as identical items which differ in their catcodes. To overcome this hurdle, we need a two-pass system:

- one step creates control sequences which contain a list of items for which `\detokenize` returns the same value;
- the other step puts all those control sequences together.

In both steps, we need to avoid duplicates, and it ends up being simpler to do the second step first, using the fact that `\csname foo\endcsname` lets `\foo` be `\relax` locally if it is `undefined`. The construction `\ifcsname foo\endcsname \csname foo\endcsname \fi` expands to `\foo` if it was undefined and lets it to `\relax`, otherwise it expands to nothing. By looping through the comma-list (using the expandable `\clist_map_function:NN`), we build a list of the form

```
\l_Xclist_<item1>_seq \l_Xclist_<item2>_seq ... \l_Xclist_<itemN>_seq
```

without duplicates.

In the second pass, we then define each of the `\l_Xclist_<itemK>_seq`. Each one of those is initially `\relax`, and we don't like this, so we test whether this is the case (with `\if_meaning:w #1 \relax`, which is simply `\ifx`), and if so, let them be an empty macro. Once we are sure that `\l_Xclist_<itemK>_seq` is a "good" sequence, we can use LaTeX3's seq macros to test whether  (not detokenized) is in `\l_Xclist_<itemK>_seq`. If it is not, we add it.

At the end of the day, we have built all the `\l_Xclist_<itemK>_seq`, each containing a sequence of all the items which give `<itemK>` when detokenized. I then do something bad, reaching for the internals of the `l3seq` module by defining `\seq_item:n`, and doing essentially `\xdef \g_Xclist_remove_clist {\g_Xclist_remove_clist}`, which expands each sequence to the correct comma-list. The small `\romannumeral` subtelty is there to remove the first comma in a relatively cheap way.

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
%
% Now we use a global clist to return the value.
% 
\clist_new:N \g_Xclist_remove_clist
%
% In the same way as in l3clist, we use a common auxiliary function
% for removing duplicates locally or globally.
%
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \Xclist_remove_duplicates:N #1 {
  \Xclist_remove_duplicates_aux:N #1
  \clist_set_eq:NN #1 \g_Xclist_remove_clist
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \Xclist_gremove_duplicates:N #1 {
  \Xclist_remove_duplicates_aux:N #1 
  \clist_gset_eq:NN #1 \g_Xclist_remove_clist
}
%
% The rough idea is to define one variable per element "#1"
% of the clist, and only add the element if the corresponding
% variable is not defined. 
% 
% with name "\g_clist_remove_\tl_to_str:n{#1}_seq",
% containing the sequence of all "#1" with the same detokenization.
% This is necessary to cater for the possibility that two different
% 
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \Xclist_remove_duplicates_aux:N #1 
  {
    \group_begin:
    \tl_gset:Nx \g_Xclist_remove_clist 
      {
        \clist_map_function:NN #1 \Xclist_remove_duplicates_aux_ii:n
      }
    \clist_map_inline:Nn #1 
      {
        \exp_args:Nc \Xclist_remove_duplicates_aux_iii:Nn
        {l_Xclist_\tl_to_str:n{##1}_seq} {##1}
      }
    \cs_set:Npn \seq_item:n ##1 { , \exp_not:n {##1} }
    \cs_set:Npn\seq_elt:w##1\seq_elt_end:{\seq_item:n{##1}}%for older l3seq.
    \tl_gset:Nx \g_Xclist_remove_clist 
      { 
        \exp_after:wN \use_none:n \tex_romannumeral:D -`\0% remove leading ","
        \g_Xclist_remove_clist 
      }
    \group_end:
  }
\cs_new:Npn \Xclist_remove_duplicates_aux_ii:n #1 
  {
    \reverse_if:N \if_cs_exist:w l_Xclist_\tl_to_str:n {#1}_seq\cs_end:
      \cs:w l_Xclist_\tl_to_str:n{#1}_seq \cs_end:
    \fi:
  }
\cs_new:Npn \Xclist_remove_duplicates_aux_iii:Nn #1 #2
  {
    \if_meaning:w #1 \tex_relax:D
       \seq_clear:N #1
    \fi:
    \seq_if_in:NnF #1 {#2} {\seq_put_right:Nn #1 {#2}}
  }
```

A very basic test:

```
\clist_new:N \l_my_clist
\clist_set:Nn \l_my_clist {a,b,c,d,e,\f,\g\h,a,b,c,\f,d,e,\g\h}
\clist_put_right:Nx \l_my_clist {\string a}
\clist_put_right:Nx \l_my_clist {\string b}
\clist_put_right:Nx \l_my_clist {\string c}
\clist_put_right:Nx \l_my_clist {\string d}
\clist_put_right:Nx \l_my_clist {\string e}

\clist_show:N \l_my_clist
\Xclist_remove_duplicates:N \l_my_clist
\clist_show:N \l_my_clist
```

Comment: I get "Undefined control sequence" because `\seq_elt:w` is being expanded to `\ERROR`, which shouldn't happen.

Comment: @egreg: that's because the internal implementation of `l3seq` changed recently. Let me add a line to fix that.

Comment: @whomever was editing: sorry, I just saw it when clicking on the submit button.

Comment: I should add that this method has a major drawback in that it can exhaust TeX's memory for control sequences (in my installation, when a comma-list reaches 60000 items or so), whereas some quadratic methods are less demanding on that kind of memory.

Comment: In fact, it seems that even after closing a group, local definitions within it have already spent part of the hash size, which is not retrieved. If this is right, then it means that 60000 is the total number of items that can be treated in total in a given run. I'm not too sure about this, though.

Answer (score 4):

I was inspired by Bruno's solution but I suggest to use *only one full expandable pass*. The main effect is reached by `\expandafter\ifx\csname foo\endcsname\fi` which expands to nothing but sets the `\foo` to `\relax`. This is only sole assignment done at expand processor level. All other assignments are done in main processor of TeX.

```
\def\noduplicate#1,{\ifx,#1,\else
   \ifcsname dup:#1\endcsname
   \else #1,\expandafter\ifx \csname dup:#1\endcsname \relax \fi
   \fi
   \expandafter\noduplicate \fi
}
\def\alist{john,mary,george,australia,australia,mary}

\edef\alist{\expandafter\noduplicate\alist,,}
\message{\meaning\alist}

\end
```

The e-TeX is needed because of `\ifcsname` is used. The string pool and hash table is (unfortunatelly) allocated but there is no way to deallocating them.

Comment: You can use grouping to prevent the allocation issue.

Comment: No. The _meanig_ of control sequences are deallocated at the end of the group but string pool and hash table is not deallocated.

Answer (score 1):

The LaTeX2e kernel only provides `\@removeelement`, which will remove a specific element (and is used to remove class options from the global list). So you will need to either code your own or use a version pre-written in a package (for example `\clist_remove_duplicates:Nn` from [`expl3`](http://ctan.org/pkg/expl3)).