# How to deduplicate and sort a list of \pagerefs?

Tags: pdftex, lists, programming

I have a document comprised of three large, multi-page tables, all of which have links to items in a list of figures at the end. By generating md5 labels when I generate the latex for the tables, I can include links back to the originating tables. However, multiple items linking to a figure will often be on the same page, leading to monstrosities like this:

```
Figure 31 - This figure was referenced on pages 4, 4, 4, 14, 17, 17, 27, 30, 30, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 19, 19, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 32, 32, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34 34, and 34.
```

In the generated document, each of those page numbers is a link back to the line in the table which referenced that figure.

I'd like to accomplish two things:

1. Eliminate duplicates, so that there is only a reference to the first table entry on a given page
2. (optional) Sort the list by the page number

I've seen the list deduplication question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16687/removing-duplicates-from-a-list), but I am new to latex and I can't even get my minimal working example, posted below, to actually work:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,openany,oneside]{book}

\makeatletter
\def\removeduplicates#1#2{\begingroup
  \let\@tempa#1%
  \def\@tempb{}%
  \@for\next:=\@tempa\do
    {\@ifundefined{lstel@\next}
      {\edef\@tempb{\@tempb,\next}
       \expandafter\let\csname lstel@\next\endcsname\@empty}
      {}%
    }%
  \edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand#2{\@tempb}}\x
  \expandafter\strip@comma#2\@nil#2}
\def\strip@comma,#1\@nil#2{\def#2{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% some labels on page 1
\section{John} \label{john}
john doe
\section{Mary} \label{mary}
mary sue

%move to page 2
\clearpage
\section{George} \label{george}
george weasley
\section{Australia} \label{australia}
crocodile dundee

%new page, where the references are
\clearpage
\section{References}

\def\alist{\pageref{john},\pageref{mary},\pageref{george},\pageref{australia},\pageref{australia},\pageref{john}}   
\removeduplicates\alist\blist

\show\blist
\show\alist

\removeduplicates\alist\alist
\show\alist

\end{document}
```

When I try to run that, a simple modification of the example from the link, I get about a dozen errors for each of the `\renewduplicates` lines, complaining about missing `\endcsname`, extra `\endcsname`, and extra `\else`. I have no idea how to go about debugging that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `\edef` and `\pageref` cannot be used in this context, nor can it appear in `\csname...\endcsname`

Avoiding full expansion will work, together with stringifying the first level expansion of `\next` when in `\csname...\endcsname`.

```
\providecommand{\expandonce}{\unexpanded\expandafter}
\makeatletter
\def\removeduplicates#1#2{\begingroup
  \let\@tempa#1%
  \def\@tempb{}%
  \@for\next:=\@tempa\do
    {\@ifundefined{lstel@\detokenize\expandafter{\next}}
      {\edef\@tempb{\expandonce{\@tempb},\expandonce{\next}}
       \expandafter\let\csname lstel@\detokenize\expandafter{\next}\endcsname\@empty}
      {}%
    }%
  \edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand#2{\expandonce{\@tempb}}}\x
  \expandafter\strip@comma#2\@nil#2}
\def\strip@comma,#1\@nil#2{\def#2{#1}}
\makeatother
```

However, there's a slicker way:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,openany,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\removeduplicates}{mm}
 {
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq { , } #1
  \seq_remove_duplicates:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \tl_set:Nx #2 { \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { , } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
% some labels on page 1
\section{John} \label{john}
john doe
\section{Mary} \label{mary}
mary sue

%move to page 2
\clearpage
\section{George} \label{george}
george weasley
\section{Australia} \label{australia}
crocodile dundee

%new page, where the references are
\clearpage
\section{References}

\def\alist{\pageref{john},\pageref{mary},\pageref{george},%
  \pageref{australia},\pageref{australia},\pageref{john}}   

\removeduplicates\alist\blist

\show\blist
\show\alist

\removeduplicates\alist\alist
\show\alist

\end{document}
```

Here's the output on my terminal:

```
> \blist=macro:
->\pageref {john},\pageref {mary},\pageref {george},\pageref {australia}.
l.37 \show\blist

? 
> \alist=macro:
->\pageref {john},\pageref {mary},\pageref {george},\pageref {australia},\pager
ef {australia},\pageref {john}.
l.38 \show\alist

? 
> \alist=macro:
->\pageref {john},\pageref {mary},\pageref {george},\pageref {australia}.
l.41 \show\alist

?
```

Sorting is impossible at this level.

---

If you want to remove the page number duplicates, rather than the `\pageref{...}` duplicates, you need the expandable version of `\pageref` provided by `refcount`. I'll show the code in the two version. First `expl3`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,openany,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\removeduplicates}{mm}
 {
  \clist_set:Nx \l_tmpa_clist { #1 }
  \clist_remove_duplicates:N \l_tmpa_clist
  \tl_set:NV #2 \l_tmpa_clist
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
% some labels on page 1
\section{John} \label{john}
john doe
\section{Mary} \label{mary}
mary sue

%move to page 2
\clearpage
\section{George} \label{george}
george weasley
\section{Australia} \label{australia}
crocodile dundee

%new page, where the references are
\clearpage
\section{References}

\def\alist{\getpagerefnumber{john},\getpagerefnumber{mary},\getpagerefnumber{george},%
  \getpagerefnumber{australia},\getpagerefnumber{australia},\getpagerefnumber{john}}   

\removeduplicates\alist\blist

\show\blist
\show\alist

\removeduplicates\alist\alist
\show\alist

\alist

\blist

\end{document}
```

Then the “classical” version:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,openany,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{refcount}

\makeatletter
\def\removeduplicates#1#2{\begingroup
  \let\@tempa#1%
  \def\@tempb{}%
  \@for\next:=\@tempa\do
    {\@ifundefined{lstel@\next}
      {\edef\@tempb{\@tempb,\next}%
       \expandafter\let\csname lstel@\next\endcsname\@empty}
      {}%
    }%
  \edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand#2{\@tempb}}\x
  \expandafter\strip@comma#2\@nil#2}
\def\strip@comma,#1\@nil#2{\def#2{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% some labels on page 1
\section{John} \label{john}
john doe
\section{Mary} \label{mary}
mary sue

%move to page 2
\clearpage
\section{George} \label{george}
george weasley
\section{Australia} \label{australia}
crocodile dundee

%new page, where the references are
\clearpage
\section{References}

\def\alist{\getpagerefnumber{john},\getpagerefnumber{mary},\getpagerefnumber{george},\getpagerefnumber{australia},\getpagerefnumber{australia},\getpagerefnumber{john}}   
\removeduplicates\alist\blist

\show\blist
\show\alist

\removeduplicates\alist\alist
\show\alist

\blist

\alist

\end{document}
```

Both versions define `\blist` and redefine `\alist` to contain “1,2”.

---

A version that uses the built list for printing hyperlinks to the pages.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,openany,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\createlinks}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnx \l_tmpa_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_remove_duplicates:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpb_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { \hyperlink { page.##1 } { ##1 } }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { ,~ }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nnx }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
% some labels on page 1
\section{John} \label{john}
john doe
\section{Mary} \label{mary}
mary sue

%move to page 2
\clearpage
\section{George} \label{george}
george weasley
\section{Australia} \label{australia}
crocodile dundee

%new page, where the references are
\clearpage
\section{References}

\def\alist{\getpagerefnumber{john},\getpagerefnumber{mary},\getpagerefnumber{george},%
  \getpagerefnumber{australia},\getpagerefnumber{australia},\getpagerefnumber{john}}   

\createlinks\alist

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm, neither variant appears to work for me. The output of \blist given the first approach is just 1, not 1 2 as expected. In contrast, the output of \blist given the second approach is 1 1 2 2, which correctly eliminated two of the duplicates, but not all of them.

Comment: @coriolinus I fixed the first approach. But you really need the *expanded* version for being able to remove all page number duplicates. I get, as expected, “1,1,2,2”.

Comment: @coriolinus I added the “expanded” version.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying now to re-enable links to each page. I tried making a new function with the body `\clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } {\hyperlink{page.##1}{##1 }}`, but that gives an error: Line 47: Paragraph ended before \linkpages was complete. Any ideas how I could fix that?

Comment: @coriolinus I'll add this version.