# Print only Unique numbers

Tags: macros

Have list of numbers captured through the command `\Numbers`. When using `\PrintNumbers`, it should print only the unique numbers.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\gdef\PrintNumbers{}
\def\Numbers#1{\g@addto@macro\PrintNumbers{#1 }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Numbers{1}
\Numbers{2}
\Numbers{3}
\Numbers{3}
\Numbers{4}
\Numbers{4}
\PrintNumbers

\end{document}
```

Present Output:

```
1 2 3 3 4 4
```

Required Output:

```
1 2 3 4
```

Command `\removeduplicates` [from this Link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229436/how-to-deduplicate-and-sort-a-list-of-pagerefs) requires the single input unlike the requested.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a command for each number that is unique, and condition on the existence of that command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\PrintNumbers}{}
\newcommand{\Numbers}[1]{%
  \ifcsname @number@#1\endcsname% Check if macro exists
    \unskip
  \else% ...if not...
    \@namedef{@number@#1}{}% ...define it and...
    \g@addto@macro\PrintNumbers{#1 }% ...add it to the list
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Numbers{1}
\Numbers{2}
\Numbers{3}
\Numbers{3}
\Numbers{4}
\Numbers{4}
\PrintNumbers

\end{document}
```

Comment: That was a swift reply... Works fine...

Comment: @KumareshPS: It's far quicker to load up some memory with macro definitions than to run through a list and check for the existence of a number. Can be done, but would be slower.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `xparse` and `expl3`. In the following version of the code the duplicates are removed at printing time. It could easily be done when `\Numbers` is called; that depends on how you want to use the list. Note that the built list remains untouched by `\PrintNumbers`, so it can be used in different ways later.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Numbers}{m}
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_kumaresh_numbers_seq { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\PrintNumbers}{O{~}}
 {
  \seq_set_eq:NN \l_kumaresh_temp_seq \l_kumaresh_numbers_seq
  \seq_remove_duplicates:N \l_kumaresh_temp_seq
  \seq_use:Nn \l_kumaresh_temp_seq { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_kumaresh_numbers_seq
\seq_new:N \l_kumaresh_temp_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Numbers{1}
\Numbers{2}
\Numbers{3}
\Numbers{3}
\Numbers{4}
\Numbers{4}
\PrintNumbers

\PrintNumbers[--]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here is another version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\PrintNumbers{}
\def\Numbers#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname Numbers@#1\endcsname\relax%
    \g@addto@macro\PrintNumbers{#1 }%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname Numbers@#1\endcsname{0}%
  \fi%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Numbers{1}
\Numbers{2}
\Numbers{3}
\Numbers{3}
\Numbers{4}
\Numbers{4}
\PrintNumbers

\end{document}
```

Comment: Appreciated your support...