# Filter datatool database for duplicates

Tags: datatool, database

I just want to filter a given database for duplicates and remove them. In my specific case the database is loaded from an external `.csv` data and has only one single column. But to keep it simple in this MWE, I just created the DB `floorRawData` and filled it up with some data.

Because I did not find any out of the box function to remove duplicates, I tried it on my own like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}
\DTLnewdb{floorFilteredData}
\DTLnewdb{floorRawData}

\DTLnewrow{floorRawData}
\DTLnewdbentry{floorRawData}{FloorRaw}{groundFloor}
\DTLnewrow{floorRawData}
\DTLnewdbentry{floorRawData}{FloorRaw}{upperFloor}
\DTLnewrow{floorRawData}
\DTLnewdbentry{floorRawData}{FloorRaw}{groundFloor}
\DTLnewrow{floorRawData}
\DTLnewdbentry{floorRawData}{FloorRaw}{basementFloor}
\DTLdisplaydb{floorRawData}\\ % Result as expected!

\newcommand{\noDBentry}{FALSE}

\DTLforeach*{floorRawData}{\floorRaw=FloorRaw}
{
    \noindent FloorRaw Element: \floorRaw\\
    \DTLifdbempty{floorFilteredData}
    {
        \DTLnewrow{floorFilteredData}
        \DTLnewdbentry{floorFilteredData}{FloorFiltered}{\floorRaw}
        \\\DTLdisplaydb{floorFilteredData}\\[5mm]
    }
    {
        \DTLforeach{floorFilteredData}{\floorFiltered=FloorFiltered}
        {
            FloorFiltered Element: \floorFiltered\\ % Why is this element "upperFloor" and not "groundFloor"?
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\floorRaw}{\floorFiltered}}
            {
                \renewcommand{\noDBentry}{TRUE}
            }{}
        }
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\noDBentry}{FALSE}}
        {
            Add new data: \floorFiltered % Never called!
            \DTLnewrow{floorFilteredData}
            \DTLnewdbentry{floorFilteredData}{FloorFiltered}{\floorRaw}
        }
        {
            \renewcommand{\noDBentry}{FALSE}
        }  
    }
}

\DTLdisplaydb{floorFilteredData}\\

\end{document}
```

In this MWE I just parse through the `floorRawData` DB and check if the current element is already part of my `floorFilteredData` DB. When it is part, then I will not add a new element in `floorFilteredData` DB otherwise I want to add this element.

So at the end I expect a `floorFilteredData` DB where in every line is a different `\floorFiltered` element.

But as you can see, the `\floorFiltered` element always seems to be the same element like `\floorRaw`.

Therefore my expectation is, that `\DTLforeach{floorFilteredData}{\floorFiltered=FloorFiltered}` will not start from the beginning.

I had a look at the datatool package manual p.58 https://texdoc.org/serve/datatool/0 But I didn't get the correct clue out of this...

[image: Nested \foreach]

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching, I found this great [FAQ](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/faq.php?itemlabel=dtlexpandnewvalue) from the datatool package maintainer Nicola L. C. Talbot :) I would like to highlight this topic even more in the [package manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/datatool/0) on p.43.

The solution is to add `\dtlexpandnewvalue` before you are adding DB elements programmatically. **And that's it!**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}
\DTLnewdb{floorFilteredData}
\DTLnewdb{floorRawData}

\DTLnewrow{floorRawData}
\DTLnewdbentry{floorRawData}{FloorRaw}{groundFloor}
\DTLnewrow{floorRawData}
\DTLnewdbentry{floorRawData}{FloorRaw}{upperFloor}
\DTLnewrow{floorRawData}
\DTLnewdbentry{floorRawData}{FloorRaw}{groundFloor}
\DTLnewrow{floorRawData}
\DTLnewdbentry{floorRawData}{FloorRaw}{basementFloor}
\DTLdisplaydb{floorRawData}\\ % Result as expected!

\newcommand{\noDBentry}{FALSE}
\dtlexpandnewvalue % Just add this line

\DTLforeach*{floorRawData}{\floorRaw=FloorRaw}
{
    \DTLifdbempty{floorFilteredData}
    {
        \DTLnewrow{floorFilteredData}
        \DTLnewdbentry{floorFilteredData}{FloorFiltered}{\floorRaw}
    }
    {
        \DTLforeach{floorFilteredData}{\floorFiltered=FloorFiltered}
        {
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\floorRaw}{\floorFiltered}}
            {
                \renewcommand{\noDBentry}{TRUE}
            }{}
        }
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\noDBentry}{FALSE}}
        {
            \DTLnewrow{floorFilteredData}
            \DTLnewdbentry{floorFilteredData}{FloorFiltered}{\floorRaw}
        }
        {
            \renewcommand{\noDBentry}{FALSE}
        }  
    }
}

\DTLdisplaydb{floorFilteredData}\\

\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT**
[image: Output]